# How to iterate over an array in overlapping groups of n elements?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, methods

Say you have this array:

```
arr = w|one two three|
```

How can I iterate over it by having two consecutive elements as block arguments like this:

```
1st cycle: |nil, 'one'|
2nd cycle: |'one', 'two'|
3rd cycle: |'two', 'three'|
```

Sofar I came only with this:

```
arr.each_index { |i| [i - 1 < 0 ? nil: arr[i - 1], arr[i]] }
```

Any better solutions? Is there something like `each(n)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `nil` as the first element of your `arr` and use [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) method:

```
arr.unshift(nil).each_cons(2).map { |first, second| [first, second] }
# => [[nil, "one"], ["one", "two"], ["two", "three"]]
```

(I'm using `map` here to show what exactly is returned on each iteration)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was sure there's something like that, I just didn't know it. Thank you :)

Comment: nice. but probably not change the original array.

`([nil] + arr).each_const(2)`

Answer (score 6):

```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_cons(2).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```